# Does the equation $x^k+y^k-z^k-w^k=3\ (k>3)$ have a solution over $\mathbb N$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Clearly,
$$3=0^2+2^2-1^2-0^2\ \ \mbox{and}\ \ 3=4^3 +4^3-5^3-0^3.$$

**Question.** Let $k>3$ be an integer. Does the equation
$$ x^k+y^k-z^k-w^k=3\quad \ (x,y,z,w\in\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,\ldots\})\tag{1}$$
have a solution?

I have checked that the equation $(1)$ has no solution with $\max\{z,w\}\le 500$ for $k=4,5$. Also, for $k=6,7$, the equation $(1)$ has no solution with $\max\{z,w\}\le 300$. I conjecture that $(1)$ has no solution for each integer $k>3$.

By the way, I also conjecture that any integer can be written as $x^3+y^3-z^3-w^3$ with $x,y,z,w\in\mathbb N$ (see https://oeis.org/A351338). This is stronger than Sierpinski's conjecture that each integer is a sum of four integer cubes.

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: Though the case $2\mid k$ is easy as pointed out by Will Sawin, the case $2\nmid k$ remains quite challenging.  The equation $(1)$ has certain mixed flavor in view of Fermat's Last Theorem and Catalan's equation.

Answer (score 7):

There are no solutions for $k>2$ even.

For $k$ even, $n^k$ is congruent to $1$ mod $8$ as soon as $n$ is odd. If $k>2$, then $n^k$ is conruent to $0$ mod $8$ as soon as $n$ is even.

So $x^k + y^k - z^k -w^k$ is congruent mod $8$ to a sum of two terms that are $0$ or $1$ and two terms that are $0$ or $-1$, i.e. to $-2, -1, 0,1$ or $2$.

Since none of these is $3$, there are no solutions modulo $8$, and thus no integer solutions.

Comment: Doesn't the same idea work for multiples of Germain primes? If $p$ is a Germain prime then $x^{k} \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{2p+1}$ for all multiples $k$ of $p$.

Comment: @NickS No, since having $-1$ and not just $1$ available lets you represent $3$: $ 1 + 1 - (-1) - 0 = 3$. (In fact, this shows an integer obstruction exists for odd $k$, so no congruence obstruction will work.)

Comment: Ups, you are right. Not enough coffee